# What is “Asymptotically tight time complexity”? Is this code's time complexity asymptotically tight?

Tags: c++, big-o, complexity-theory

Why is the time complexity of this code O(x*n*m)?

Is this code's time complexity asymptotically tight?

Why?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10];
    int x, y, i, j, m, n;


    cout << "\nEnter the number of rows and columns for Matrix A:::\n\n";
    cin >> x >> y;


    // x denotes number rows in matrix A
    // y denotes number columns in matrix A
    cout << "\n\nEnter elements for Matrix A :::\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix A :\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nEnter the number of rows and columns for Matrix B:::\n\n";
    cin >> m >> n;
    // m denotes number rows in matrix B
    // n denotes number columns in matrix B


    cout << "\n\nEnter elements for Matrix B :::\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> b[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\nMatrix B :\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << b[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    if (y == m)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                c[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        cout
                << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "\n\nMultiplication of Matrix A and Matrix B :\n\n";
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << "\t" << c[i][j];
            }
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\nMultiplication is not possible";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code formatting is a **HUGE MESS**

Comment: "Tightness" is a property of the bound, not of the code. If the same bound is both an upper bound and a lower bound, it's a tight bound. For example if the time complexity is at most linear **and** at least linear, you have a tight bound. If you only know an upper bound, it might turn out that there's a smaller upper bound that you didn't know. If the upper bound is also the lower bound that can't happen - there's no chance your upper bound is too high (or your lower bound is too low) so it's a tight bound.

Answer (score 0):

Because the most computations is done here:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

The approximation of number of basic operations like addition, multiplication and assignment here is `x*n*m`. That is why this algorithm has `O(x*n*m)` asymptotic. But matrix multiplication can be done faster in terms of asymptotic. Just check out related articles about matrix multiplication and big o notation.

[Complexity introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

[Faster matrix multiplication approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)